# How to fix box-shadow transition is not working on hover?

Tags: css, frontend, hover, tailwind-css

I have `box-shadow` for a `<li>` tag but my `transition` on hover is not working.

My code:

```html
<li class="shadow-outer hover:shadow-inner transition-all duration-1000 ease-in-out cursor-pointer rounded-full w-full px-6 py-2 flex flex-row justify-between">
     <span>home</span>
     <span>i</span>
</li>
```

Tailwind config:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    theme: {
        boxShadow: {
            inner: 'inset 3px 3px 3px #cdcdcd, inset -3px -3px 3px #fafafa',
            outer: '3px 3px 3px #cdcdcd, -3px -3px 3px #fafafa',
        },
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {
            boxShadow: ['hover'],
            transitionProperty: ['hover'],
            transitionDuration: ['hover'],
            transitionTimingFunction: ['hover'],
        },
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with tailwind but with the css.

Box Shadow inset cant transition to non-inset. In general animations and transitions only work from and to numeric values. So to get a transition, you need to set 0px values like this:

```
boxShadow: {
    inner:
      'inset 3px 3px 3px #cdcdcd, inset -3px -3px 3px #fafafa, 0px 0px 0px #cdcdcd, 0px 0px 0px #fafafa',
    outer:
      'inset 0px 0px 0px #cdcdcd, inset 0px 0px 0px #fafafa, 3px 3px 3px #cdcdcd, -3px -3px 3px #fafafa',
  },
```

[See working example here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/2qlzI1Mp4d)